# UIImageView with full width and variable height

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am developing an app where I want the UIImageview like instagram feed. I set the leading and trailing space to mainview as zero so width is now 100% of screen. Now how do i set the height so that it varies depending on image's scale. I tried setting content mode to Aspect Fit, but its not working and blank spaces are coming in the left and right side for a portrait mode image

Sample Image i selected
[image: Selected Image]

How it came after selecting in UIIMageView

[image: Image in UIImageView]

Comment: please show the code that have been written also share how the UI will be looking like.

Comment: set `Aspect Fill` instead `Aspect Fit` this will adjust image width without changing it's Aspect ratio.

Comment: your UIImageView is part of TableViewCell?

Comment: @Sateesh added screenshots to post

Comment: @ibnetariq no its not part of tableviewcell

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich tried that and screenshot added is the result

Comment: image you selected have higher resolution so that it is expanded out of screen

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to get Image dimension in Height and Width from server side for each image.
Then Accroding to Image Width, Image Height, Screen width you have to calculate new Image Height and Set it to ImageView Height by taking Image View Height Constraint.

```
let calculatedImageHeight = (screenWidth * imageHeight)/imageWidth
```

Comment: in the screenshot the image is not even scaled properly like its too big will adjusting height of imageview programatically fix this?

Comment: Yes it will this